# How to make an iOS app for security by using speech recognition?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I want to make an iPhone app that will record a voice and than whenever the user starts using my app. It will through some keywords to be spoken and app will record those keywords and match the voice of the existing file and the keywords file. So is there any way so that I can make such an application for security purposes?

Comment: a spoken word that can be heard by anyone around for security purposes? this is really better than password?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OpenEars makes it simple for you to add speech recognition and synthesized speech/TTS to your iPhone app quickly and easily. I hope following link helps you

http://www.politepix.com/openears/

Comment: Actually I want to do voice recognition so is it possible to do voice recognition with openears?

Comment: As far as I know there is no such library/ framework available to recognise voice for iOS. But you can google it out or if you can modify the above link framework

Comment: So is there any other way by which I can provide a secure authentication in my app? Actually I have 2 ideas for it firstly voice recognition, and 2nd one is face detection. But i think face detection is also not allowed in iOS or is it allow?

Comment: You can use fingerprint recognition technic 
http://www.freedownloadmanager.org/download/iphone-fingerprint-recognition-sdk-4135751.html

Comment: but 1 months back, finger prints was not possible. Is it possible now in iOS 6?

Comment: I have never tried it I just googled it and find out this library

Comment: Ok thanks for great help